# Special chars in $.get jQuery

Tags: jquery, utf-8

I have a file called: "CAÑUELAS.json", but when I called in $.get function, the char "Ñ" is replaced with "%C3%91", so the called file is "CA%C3%91UELAS.json". How I can make that print: "CAÑUELAS.json"?

This is my code:

```
value = "CAÑUELAS.json";

$.get('../../jsons/' + value, function(dataCoordinates) {
            ..etc
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @ShivYadav I try it and the same, replace 'Ñ' with '%C3%91'

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with a symple "hardcode". I replace all de 'Ñ' with 'N' using replace and I rename all my files that have Ñ to N.

This is the final solution:

```
value = "CAÑUELAS.json";
value = value.replace('Ñ', 'N');

$.get('../../jsons/' + value, function(dataCoordinates) {
            ..etc
```